# "Unable to start activity" says, LOGCAT

Tags: android, listview

I was trying to create a new class which should generate a ListView, but I have an error..
Error says **unable to start activity** I'm confused; can anyone tell me where the problem is, what did I do wrong or what can I do?

## CODE

```
public class ManagerView extends ListActivity{

DBAdapter db;
Cursor cr;
String arr[];


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            db = new DBAdapter(this);
            cr = db.getAllRecords();
    int i = 0;
    Cursor crr = null;
    
    try {crr = db.getRecord(4);}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    
    for (cr.moveToFirst(); !cr.moveToLast(); cr.moveToNext()){
        
        arr[i] = crr.getString(i);
        i++;
        }
        
    setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr));
    }
```

}

## ERROR

```
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tsfc/com.example.tsfc.ManagerView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.example.tsfc.DBAdapter.getAllRecords(DBAdapter.java:100)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.example.tsfc.ManagerView.onCreate(ManagerView.java:32)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-30 17:11:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: How is it not an Activity?

Comment: I created it as a Class file. It not came with an Activity.?

Comment: So there is no layout file bound this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.tsfc/com.example.tsfc.ManagerView}; have you declared
>   this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 12-30 16:35:09.451:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1049): at

make sure you have declared your activity in `AndroidManifest` as:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.tsfc.ManagerView" />
```

and 
Currently you are initializing DBAdapter in wrong place . move all database class initialization and  getAllRecords inside onCreate of ListActivity as:

```
public  class ManagerView extends ListActivity{

DBAdapter db ;
Cursor cr ;
String arr[];



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     db = new DBAdapter(ManagerView.this);
     cr = db.getAllRecords();
}

// your code here,...

}
```

Comment: The `a` in the `<activity>` tag should be lower case

Comment: @RaghavSood :Thanks Sir, i have changed it typing mistake

Comment: ....This timeit says **unable to instatiate activity**.....**access to class not allowed**

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar : try after adding public which List Activity class see my edit

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: And now we have an **unable to start activity** error... Pfff... Gonna loose my mind..

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar : plz don't loose your mind because it maybe possible you have other issues apart from these .just edit your question with latest code and logcat

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar : what is line num 100 in DBAdapter.java

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK:  public Cursor getAllRecords() 
     {
         return db.query(false, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                 KEY_READ, KEY_TYPE, KEY_NAME, KEY_MAIL, KEY_CONTENT}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
     }

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar : this answer help u or not to solve your issue if yes plz mark it as answer .Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Sorry, I wasn't online for a while, I forgot

Answer (score -1):

You have a null pointer error. Remove the error.

Or

Comment all code but setContentView() in onCreate() function and see if the activity successfully opens.

Comment: that doesn't explain very much